# Stirling's approximation fractional error

Tags: logarithms, approximation, truncation-error

Given Stirling's approximation $\ln N!$ is approximated by $N\ln N-N+\frac{1}{2}\ln N$.
I want to calculate the fractional error that comes from neglecting the third term $\frac{1}{2}\ln N$ for $N=10$ and $N=100$.
I thought it would be enough to consider $$\frac{\frac{1}{2}\ln N}{N\ln N-N+\frac{1}{2}\ln N}\ ,$$
but for $N=10$ I get $0.08$, while, according to my professor, the answer is $0.05$.
I have an identical issue with $N=100$, where I get $0.006$ instead of $0.005$.
Is there a problem with the way I am calculating the fractional error? I can't really see any other reason why I keep getting the wrong results.